# Creating alias in Linux to a file or directory whose path changes with time

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I want to create an alias to a specific log file in Linux. The only issue is the path to the file has a directory with time stamp. Every time this file is created (every time I run a script), its path changes because of time stamp. Here is an example:

```
$OUT_HOME/logs/misc/2017-03-20-11-23-24-3541-machine_name/commands/logfile.txt
```

Is there a smart way to create an alias to this file?

Comment: Are there going to be many directories like this `misc`, or always just one? And if there are many, is the file always in the latest one?

Comment: @BenjaminW. only one misc directory

Comment: Oh, I meant "*in* `misc`", sorry.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Only one file in one specific directory

Comment: The one who -ve repped should care to explain the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try somethink like that :

```
alias my_alias=$(echo $OUT_HOME/logs/misc/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%4N")-machine_name/commands/logfile.txt)
```

Comment: there seems to be sytax error. There is no matching parentheses for the first one. Can you fix this?

Comment: @user2979872 corrected the syntax. There was a missing `"` and a missing `)`

Answer (score 1):

If this folder with changing name is created by running script in which you want to create those symlink, then simply changing part assign to some variable which will be used during folder creation and symlink creation.